# Worklight Flight Ticket Sample "Function [onAuthRequired] not found."

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to run the Flight Ticket Sample Application for Worklight v6.1.0. My setup is working fine. I deployed the application as follows:

1. I imported the project zip file `FlightTicketSampleProject.zip` into my workspace.
2. I created a new web application in the server.xml file with the context root as `flightticket` and pointed the war location to `flightticket.war`. When I navigate to `http://localhost:10080/flightticket` I get the message simple index.html. Everything is fine so far.
3. I then deployed the three adapters FTAdapter, FTPushAdapter and LoginAdapter to the server.
4. Finally, I deployed the app using `Run As -> Run on Worklight Development Server`.

When I open Worklight Console and click on `Preview as Common Resources`, I get an error in Eclipse console as follows:

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0020E: Ajax request exception: There is no application in the DB with the id 'FlightTicket'. [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0117E: Error code: 1, error description: INTERNAL_ERROR, error message: FWLSE0069E: An internal error occurred during gadget request  [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]There is no application in the DB with the id 'FlightTicket'., User Identity {wl_authenticityRealm=null, FTRealm=null, wl_remoteDisableRealm=null, SampleAppRealm=null, wl_antiXSRFRealm=null, wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm=null, WorklightConsole=null, wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm=null, wl_anonymousUserRealm=null}. [project module_60_4_FlightTicket] 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0099E: An error occurred while invoking procedure  [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]FTAdapter/onAuthRequiredFWLSE0100E:  parameters: [project module_60_4_FlightTicket]{
   "arr": [
      {
         "Accept": [
            "text\/javascript, text\/html, application\/xml, text\/xml, *\/*"
         ],
         "Accept-Encoding": [
            "gzip, deflate"
         ],
         "Accept-Language": [
            "en-IN"
         ],
         "Cache-Control": [
            "no-cache"
         ],
         "Connection": [
            "Keep-Alive"
         ],
         "Content-Length": [
            "66"
         ],
         "Content-Type": [
            "application\/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
         ],
         "Cookie": [
            "testcookie=oreo; JSESSIONID=0000Ujzcx6nIYXNuXrpCFmbvqwt:040ac9eb-2103-4149-97c9-431f2113a34f"
         ],
         "Host": [
            "192.168.174.1:10080"
         ],
         "Referer": [
            "http:\/\/192.168.174.1:10080\/module_60_4_FlightTicket\/apps\/services\/preview\/FlightTicket\/common\/0\/default\/views\/socialShare.html"
         ],
         "User-Agent": [
            "Mozilla\/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident\/7.0; MALNJS; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
         ],
         "WL-Instance-Id": [
            "8k22jp5elrdat1d06sitpqeq1f"
         ],
         "X-Requested-With": [
            "XMLHttpRequest"
         ],
         "x-wl-app-version": [
            "1.0"
         ],
         "x-wl-platform-version": [
            "6.1.0.00.20131219-1900"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
Function [onAuthRequired] not found.
```

I have checked the source for the `onAuthRequired` function but I'm not able to find either the definition nor the call to the function.

Can someone tell me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just doing it wrong. Step 2 is completely not correct and no where in the Worklight documentation will you see it being asked to do.

Here's what I've done and what you should follow:

1. Downloaded the [Flight Ticket sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/FlightTicketSampleProject.zip)
2. Imported it to Eclipse running Worklight Developer Edition 6.1
3. Right-clicked on each of the adapters in the adapters folder and chose `Run As > Deploy Worklight adapter`
4. Right-clicked on the FlightTicket app in the apps folder and chose `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server`
5. Open Worklight Console
6. Ran the app in the Android Emulator

Step 4 is required! If you do not do this step, it means you do not deploy your application, which means your app will fail to connect to the Worklight Server. See the error message you've mentioned in the question. It tells you exactly that, that the app does not exist.

After login:
[image]

Comment: I followed the steps given in this [file] (http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/12_04_Running_jQuery_Mobile_based_Flight_Ticket_Sample.pdf). And in it, it says that we have to deploy the .war file to the server. However, thanks, I got the app running on simulator following your instructions. But still I'm not able to run the android app. It gives out an error: The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for android.content.Context. Fix the build path then try building this project. What to do?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing there. Delete the native folder inside the android folder and re-build the application.

Comment: There's no native folder inside the android folder.

Comment: Listen, if there is no native folder then there is no android project which means you cannot load the app to the device. If there is no native folder, you did not follow my instructions.

Comment: Why do you jump to the flight ticket sample? Please start from the FIRST TRAINING MODULE and learn about Worklight.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please ensure you don't delete the native folder under your Android project.
2. The war file is used as backend server(JAX-RS), so mobile will get the data from this war file like your real enterprise data, while worklight war is auto deployed in the eclipse, and serve as the gateway for your mobile app and adaptors will connect to the backend server REST api to get mock up data.

Comment: I got the problem sorted out. The crime was Eclipse's. It's really buggy! And thanks for this JAX-RS thingy. I didn't know about it.